# Will PDO throw an exception if execute() returns false?

Tags: php, pdo

i wonder if PDO will throw an exception or not when `execute()` returns false.

```
<?php
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname='.$dbname, $user, $pass,array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

try{
    $db->beginTransaction();
    $query = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO threads (title,perma) VALUES ("hey", "hey")');
    if(!$query->execute())
    {
        echo ":(";
    }
}catch(Exception $e){
    echo ":)";
    $db->rollBack();
}
?>
```

Is it possible to see ':('? Should i throw an exception manually?

Comment: Why don't you simply try it? Make a primitive test case (a 10 lines script) and you have your answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Will PDO throw an exception if execute() returns false?

Yes.

You can always create a test case and see it yourself

```
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=$dbname;charset=utf8", $user, $pass);
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$pdo->query("CREATE temporary TABLE executest (id int auto_increment primary key)");

$stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO executest VALUES (?)");
$stmt->execute([1]);
$stmt->execute([1]);
```